# How to generate UML diagram

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

I have a requirement to generate UML class diagrams from the Android project that I have already developed.

My project contains more than 150 java classes.

I am really confused.  Do I need to display all the classes with their relationships or is it enough to show the relationship between the main/UI classes.

Please let me know how class diagrams will develop in general.  e.g. do I need show all the classes?

Comment: it depends: class diagrams are often used to show concepts. for that purpose you do not have to show all classes, instead you show these classes which represent important concepts. maybe a package diagram could also be interesting for you.

Comment: Use [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumldesigntool/) to reverse engineer from Java to xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ObjectAID](http://www.objectaid.com/). It is free and gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You can add plugins to your IDE for UML diagram generation. e.g in Eclipse you can search and add plugin using Help>Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [eUML2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/com.soyatec.uml.doc/)

It worked for me in eclipse for generating UML diagrams from a project.

Comment: I think there is a free edition, also working for android projects

Comment: It is [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/euml2-free-edition) but seems to be outdated (the [commercial](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/euml2-studio-edition) version has the same date and no mention of being outdated ?!) Edit: or [here](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/installation/) with a an upated paid version.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ObjectAid` plugin for eclipse, but for java. I don't know if it worsk as well for Android. But it is for free and easy to use.